# Docker Drupal e solr problems with volumes

Tags: docker, drupal, solr

I have this simple setup

https://github.com/Gdr-design/drupal-docker-with-solr

Everything works perfectly but the solr container on each boot (docker up -d) generates a different volume, so the volumes pile up indefinitely ...
How can I avoid this, using the same volume all the time?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From you `docker-compose.yml` you have to add "mycores" directory to volumes key like this :

```
volumes:
  db_data:
  mycores:
```

This avoid to regenerate data on load

Comment: Not work... 
When i type 

    "docker-compose down"
and next 

    "docker-compose up -d" 
another volume is created

Maybe i should make it i run

    "Docker system prune --volumes"

when at startup, but I don't know how to do it ...

Comment: You need to use `docker down -v` to remove old volumes on shutdown, if you use volumes declaration , your volume will be persisted